# GLSL Atomics With Floats

Tags: glsl, shadow-mapping, compute-shader

I am implementing [SDSM](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/sample-distribution-shadow-maps) and in a GLSL compute shader I need to min/max vec3 values to compute the shadow map bounds. The sample implementation (in HLSL) uses vectors in "light space" that spans from 0-1 and then casts them with touint (in GLSL uintBitsToFloat) so that it can call InterlockedMinMax (atomicMin/Max) with them.

*I was wondering if it is a better idea to quantize the values to an uint using the bounding volume in light space as uints instead of moving them into the 0-1 range so integer min/max works on the float bit pattern?*

On the one hand using float bits in unit throws about about 2/3 the precision, because the sign bit and exponent are ignored. On the other hand almost all algorithms I came up to quantize the values somehow go past the 0-1 float range and would probably loose the precision anyway.

Comment: This looks like a question you could answer by writing up a method each way, and [testing the two methods on every possible input float value](https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2014/01/27/theres-only-four-billion-floatsso-test-them-all/), to compare how much precision you lose (how many input values get crunched to the same output) with one method versus the other.

Comment: Interesting approach. There are also non trivial performance considerations, but it is worth a try as it will give me an additional data point.